# Algorithm for finding datetime ranges that overlaps with another list of datetime ranges

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, datetime, overlap

I have these DatetimeIntervals

```
internal class DatetimeInterval
{
    public DateTime From { get; }
    public DateTime To { get; }

    public DatetimeInterval(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}
```

for which I use to store old `DatetimeInterval`'s and new `DatetimeInterval`'s in
`List<DatetimeInterval>()`

Given a set of new `DatetimeInterval`'s `List<List<DatetimeInterval>>()`
I would like for each set define the set of previous `DatetimeInterval`s that is overlapping with the new `DatetimeInterval`'s.

How do i do that?

I know that an Overlap can be detected by comparing two DatetimeIntevals by doing do

```
    if((start0A <= end0B) && (end0A >= start0B))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Overlap");
    }
```

but this only handles the single case.

Is there any way where I can bundle this to an

```
    List<(List<DatetimeInterval>, List<DatetimeInterval>)> OverlappingTimeStamps = newDateTimeChunks.FindOverlapping(oldDateTimes)
```

Beside doing it in a double for loop and checking each individual?
is there any smart way of finding the overlapping datetimeIntervals between two lists?

My current attempt consist of doing this like this, but it does not feel that efficient..

```
private static List<(IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval>, IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval>)> FindOverlappingPreviousRegistrations(
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval>> chunkedRegistrations,
            IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval> oldRegistrations)
        {
            List<(IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval>, IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval>)> pairedOldAndNewRegistrations = new();
            foreach (IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval> chunkedRegistration in chunkedRegistrations)
            {
                IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval> overLappingRegistrations = chunkedRegistration.Where(newRegistration =>
                    oldRegistrations.Any(oldRegistration =>
                        newRegistration.From <= oldRegistration.To && oldRegistration.To >= newRegistration.From));
                pairedOldAndNewRegistrations.Add((overLappingRegistrations, chunkedRegistration));
            }

            return pairedOldAndNewRegistrations;
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest [CodeJam](https://github.com/rsdn/CodeJam) It has `CompositeRange` which has all needed functions to work with ranges, Merging, Exclusion, Intersection, etc.

Comment: I didn't forget about you, but my answer seems to be wrong for some reason (or, at least, though the comparer is working fine, I can't get it to work with linq's intersect for some reason.)  You can see what I've tried over here: https://rextester.com/VCL36242